# How to write better Receive() in Golang for Redis(redigo) Pubsub?

Tags: go, redis, publish-subscribe, redigo

```
psc := redis.PubSubConn{c}
psc.Subscribe("example")

func Receive() {
    for {
        switch v := psc.Receive().(type) {
        case redis.Message:
            fmt.Printf("%s: message: %s\n", v.Channel, v.Data)
        case redis.Subscription:
            fmt.Printf("%s: %s %d\n", v.Channel, v.Kind, v.Count)
        case error:
            return v
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code(taken from [Redigo doc](https://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis)), if connection is lost, all subscriptions are also lost. What will be better way to recover from lost connection and resubscribe.

Comment: How about creating a [`redis.Pool`](https://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis#Pool) whose `Dial` function also subscribes to the appropriate channels.

Comment: @tim-cooper very clean way. +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use two nested loops. The outer loop gets a connection, sets up the subscriptions and then invokes the inner loop to receive messages. The inner loop executes until there's a permanent error on the connection.

```
for {
    // Get a connection from a pool
    c := pool.Get()
    psc := redis.PubSubConn{c}

    // Set up subscriptions
    psc.Subscribe("example"))

    // While not a permanent error on the connection.
    for c.Err() == nil {
        switch v := psc.Receive().(type) {
        case redis.Message:
            fmt.Printf("%s: message: %s\n", v.Channel, v.Data)
        case redis.Subscription:
            fmt.Printf("%s: %s %d\n", v.Channel, v.Kind, v.Count)
        case error:
            fmt.Printf(err)
        }
    }
    c.Close()
}
```

This example uses a Redigo [pool](http://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis#Pool) to get connections.  An alternative is to dial a connection directly:

```
 c, err := redis.Dial("tcp", serverAddress)
```

Comment: Tim Cooper's solution in comment is more cleaner. Dial takes care of subscription during reconnects. Thanks +1

Comment: @aloksrivastava78 Subscribe from dial prevents use of pool for other purposes in the application, moves subscription code further away from receiving code and is not allowed per redigo documentation.